Can a software vendor prohibit use of their open source / community edition software (GPLv3) after subscribing to their Enterprise license?
A software vendor who offers a product under both an open source (under GPLv3) license as well as an Enterprise license has the following terms in their Enterprise agreement:

Subscriber may not, and will not permit or induce any third party to:
(i) decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble or otherwise attempt to
reconstruct or discover the source code, underlying ideas or
algorithms of any components of the Software; (ii) alter, modify,
translate, adapt in any way, or prepare any derivative work based upon
the Software; (iii) rent, lease, sublicense, sell, distribute or
otherwise transfer the Software or any copy thereof; (iv) use the
Software to operate a service-bureau; (v) remove any proprietary
notices from the Software or any Documentation or other materials
furnished or made available hereunder; or (vi) run or use any version
or edition of the product software licensed under the AGPL, AGPLv3 with
Commons Clause, GPL or any other open source license (including,
without limitation, the Community or Enterprise editions) in the same
Project or system identified on an Order Form in which Subscriber uses
or has used the Software licensed hereunder, during the term of the
Agreement and for thirty-six (36) months thereafter.

This seems to prohibit moving to the open source license after signing an enterprise agreement. Is prohibiting the use of an open source license in this context, legal under GPLv3? i.e. can a vendor stop you from using their free version after signing up to an enterprise agreement?

td;dr: no, but they can prohibit the use of their enterprise software after you use the GPL version.

Once you have downloaded the GPL-licensed community edition of the software you may use it under this license.
The clause in the license agreement of the enterprise edition may be a valid clause in that context, so using the community edition may constitute a breach of the license agreement of the enterprise edition and you should seek legal advice w.r.t. the legal consequences (damages) you may encounter. You may be liable to pay a 'fine'. But the clause does not take away the rights you received by downloading the community edition.
Please note that the legal language includes the words "in the same Project or system", which strongly reduces the scope of this clause. You will need to check the definition of 'Project' in the agreement.

I agree the "same project" language is key here -- I wonder if the intent is a belt-and-suspenders clarification that the Enterprise version is not GPL compatible (i.e., you can't incorporate it in an AGPL network service just like you can't include any other GPL-incompatible software, either)

We can only speculate about the intentions behind clause (vi). My initial thoughts were that the vendor wants to prevent that paid technical support for an enterprise edition project quickly moves into a community edition, or to prevent that code from Enterprise edition and community edition gets mixed up under GPL. But all these theories are speculation.

Thanks Martin_in_AUT. The use case is that we don't need any features from the Enterprise version and are happy to use the open source version, but this clause appears to prohibit us using the open source version, for 36 months after our enterprise license agreement expires. @apsillers the definition of Project is "Software and Services ordered by Subscriber for a particular use case (the
“Project”)".

usually the main difference between community version and enterprise version is in the license, not in the (sometimes enhanced) features. The community version license might force you to provide source code of your entire project, possibly including your company's trade secrets, while the enterprise version license allows you to keep that hidden.

@Marko Sounds like a question for your company's legal department. The "and for 36 months after" sounds potentially unreasonable. On the other hand, since there's an open source version, there's probably no way they can legally prevent you from using a fork of that product. Because of the way open source works, I doubt they can write legal language that would cover all possible forks of a particular program; ultimately the contract is going to have to identify a particular program by name; so, you can just use "something else".
